# Delphi ADO SQL Syntax Error

Tags: sql, delphi, syntax

I am getting an Syntax Error when processing the following lines of code. Especially on the AQ_Query.Open;

```
procedure THauptfenster.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    option: TZahlerArray;
begin
    option := werZahlte;
    AQ_Query.Close;
  AQ_Query.SQL.Clear;
  AQ_Query.SQL.Add('USE wgwgwg;');
  AQ_Query.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO abrechnung ');
  AQ_Query.SQL.Add('(`datum`, `titel`, `betrag`, `waldemar`, `jonas`, `ali`, `ben`)');
  AQ_Query.SQL.Add(' VALUES ');
  AQ_Query.SQL.Add('(:datum, :essen, :betrag, :waldemar, :jonas, :ali, :ben);');
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('datum').Value := DateToStr(mcDatum.Date);
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('essen').Value := ledTitel.Text;
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('betrag').Value := ledPreis.Text;
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('waldemar').Value := option[0];
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('jonas').Value := option[1];
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('ali').Value := option[2];
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('ben').Value := option[3];
  AQ_Query.Open;
end;
```

The error:

[image: SQL Error]

I am using MySQL Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. USE and INSERT are two different SQL
   commands.
2. MySQL does not support so
   called "Batches".

=> you have to call these commands one-by-one

Comment: Ok. I Have now two different statements. Still, I need to call AQ_Query.ExecSql in order to insert. Open does not work because it says: "AQ_Query does not return any data."

Still, it does not update in the DBGrid. How to update it?

Comment: Yes, you use Open for queries that return results otherwise use ExecSQL.  Where did any DBGrid feature in the original question ?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're using backticks on the third `AQ_Query.SQL.Add` line, when you need to use normal single quotes.

Comment: Yep, that's the line the error message points to and I don't see anything else in there...

Comment: Actually, since the items in backticks are apparently column names, there shouldn't be a need for any kind of punctuation at all.

Comment: You could surround the column names with square brackets. '([datum], [titel], [betrag] ... although its not required.

Comment: The error message points to the INSERT statement, not the columns list.  (Line #2 is the INSERT statement, line #1 is the USE statement).  See Dmitry's answer - I think he is right.  I don't think you can use an ADO query object to execute a script, only an individual statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the database in the sql script.

```
AQ_Query.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO wgwgwg.dbo.abrechnung ');
  AQ_Query.SQL.Add('(`wgwgwg.dbo.abrechnung.datum`, `wgwgwg.dbo.abrechnungtitel`, `wgwgwg.dbo.abrechnungbetrag`, `wgwgwg.dbo.abrechnungwaldemar`, `wgwgwg.dbo.abrechnungjonas`, `wgwgwg.dbo.abrechnungali`, `wgwgwg.dbo.abrechnungben`)');

  AQ_Query.SQL.Add(' VALUES ');

  AQ_Query.SQL.Add('(:datum, :essen, :betrag, :waldemar, :jonas, :ali, :ben);');
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('datum').Value := DateToStr(mcDatum.Date);
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('essen').Value := ledTitel.Text;
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('betrag').Value := ledPreis.Text;
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('waldemar').Value := option[0];
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('jonas').Value := option[1];
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('ali').Value := option[2];
  AQ_Query.Parameters.ParamByName('ben').Value := option[3];
```

You can also make a new connection to  wgwgwg and refer your AQ_Query to the new connection

Comment: where comes that dbo in wgwgwg.dbo.abrechnung.datum from?

Comment: Database Owner (dbo)

The dbo is a user that has implied permissions to perform all activities in the database. Any member of the sysadmin fixed server role who uses a database is mapped to the special user inside each database called dbo. Also, any object created by any member of the sysadmin fixed server role belongs to dbo automatically.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905208%28SQL.80%29.aspx